# CSS for elements following or preceding another element, not nested

Tags: html, css

I am using markdown to write my text, so I do not have control over the HTML elements. Therefore, this is given:

```
<h2>Headline</h2>
<p>A paragraph</p> // standard bottom-margin to next <p>
<p>Another paragraph</p> // double bottom-margin should apply here because the next element is h2

<h2>Another Headline</h2>
<p>And another paragraph</p> standard bottom-margin to next <p>
```

Is there a css-related approach --- or any at all --- to apply a larger margin between `<p>` and the next `<h2>` than between all the other `<p>` to `<p>` transitions?

I'd like to explicitly control those `<p>`s that come before a new `<h2>`, but not any other.

I'm using `float` so that a simple `<h2>` `top-margin` does not help.

This is what my site looks like:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't a top margin on the `<h2>` suffice?

Comment: That's a good idea, but  what I did not talk about is my use of `float`. I edited my post for clarity.

Comment: You don't use any wrapper elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the sibling selector?

```
h2+p {/*your styles here*/}
```

Reference: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: It would have to be `h2 + p`.

Comment: i think the first version was right: p+h2{margin-top:20px;} /*the h2 that comes after the p will have a margin 20px from top */

Comment: If you want the h2 to have a top margin, yeah, but if you want the p to have a bottom margin instead, this is correct. Both works.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: As per your edit this isn't what you're looking for.

You can control the h2's instead, for instance:

```
h2:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

This will create a margin of 10px above every h2 except the first.

Answer (score 1):

`h2:before {display:block;margin-top:20px;height:20px;content:"";background:#aaa;}`

rough example http://jsfiddle.net/eHreL/